# quiero ocultar botones de autorizar, eliminar. Después de darle al botón de autorizar cambiando el estado en mi columna estado(laravel 9- Vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, php8, laravel-9

> este es mi tabla y botones, en el boton de autorizacion, !estadoAutorizado && can, ahi estoy poniendo mi condicion para cuando le de click, cambie de estado en mi columna estado y quiero que se oculte el mismo boton de autorizar y eliminar

```
'<tbody>
      <tr
        v-for="vacacion in vacacions"
        :key="vacacion.ID"
        :class="[vacacion.DELETED_ID > 0 ? 'table-danger' : '']"
      >
        <td class="text-center">{{ vacacion.ID }}</td>
        <td>{{ vacacion.CARNET }}</td>
        <td>{{ vacacion.ESTADO }}<span v-if="vacacion.autorizadoId === vacacion.ID">*</span> </td>
        <td>{{ vacacion.NOMBRE_COMPLETO }}</td>
        <td>{{ vacacion.FECHA_SOLICITUD }}</td>
        <td>{{ vacacion.OBSERVACION }}</td>
        <td>{{ vacacion.FECHA_INICIO_SOLICITUD }}</td>
        <td>{{ vacacion.FECHA_FIN_SOLICITUD }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <div v-if="vacacion.DELETED_ID == 0" >
            
            <a
             v-if="!estadoAutorizado && can('recursoshumanos.vacacion.updateEstado')"   
              href="javascript:;"
              @click="autorizacion(vacacion.ID)"
              class="btn btn-outline bg-teal-800 text-teal-800 btn-icon rounded-round ml-1">
            
              <i class="icon-user-check"></i>
            </a>
              <a
              v-if="can('recursoshumanos.vacacion.destroy')"   
              href="javascript:;"
              @click="eliminarVacacion(vacacion.ID)"
              class="btn btn-outline bg-danger-400 text-danger-800 btn-icon rounded-round ml-1"
            >
              <i class="icon-trash"></i>
            </a>'
```

> aqui en data en el mismo archivo Vuejs estoy declarando mi booleano:

```
data() {
      return {
        vacacions: [],
        estadoAutorizado: false,
      };
    },
```

> y en la parte final en los metodos, en la misma carpeta Vuejs esta mi metodo modal para autorizar y tambien esta ahi mi booleando cambiando el estado.

```
autorizacion(id){
        autorizacion_modal("/recursoshumanos/vacacion/" + id);
        this.estadoAutorizado = true;
      },
```